# mysql check that value does not match multiple values

Tags: mysql

I wrote this mysql statement.

```
my $sql = "SELECT $col_field1 FROM $table_name WHERE (cyp2d6 <> 'ERROR') OR (cyp2d6 <> '1') OR (cyp2d6 IS NULL) AND (cyp2c19 <> 'ERROR') OR (cyp2c19 <> '1') OR (cyp2c19 IS NULL)";
```

If a row does does not contain any columns with 'ERROR' or '1', then I want to **do something** with the data.

Here's a small example.

```
+--------------------+--------------------------+--------+---------+
| accession_number   | dated                    | cyp2d6 | cyp2c19 |
+--------------------+--------------------------+--------+---------+
| AIB14-1116-0000453 | Mon May 12 14:42:43 2014 | NULL   | ERROR   | 
+--------------------+--------------------------+--------+---------+
```

When I execute this statement my code will **do something** when it isn't suppose to. The 'ERROR' value in column cyp2c19, should not let my code do anything. I believe this is happening because of my mysql query above. Particularly `(cyp2c19 <> '1')`. Because cyp2c19 does not equal 1 it lets me **do something**.

How am I able to check if my column value does not match multiple values? I hope this makes since. It was hard to explain.

Edit.

I changed the statement base on the other post and still didn't do what I wanted. What concept am I missing?

```
my $sql = "SELECT $col_field1 FROM $table_name WHERE (cyp2d6 <> 'ERROR' OR cyp2d6 <> '1' OR cyp2d6 IS NULL) AND (cyp2c19 <> 'ERROR' OR cyp2c19 <> '1' OR cyp2c19 IS NULL)";
```

Comment: Thanks. My searches didn't find it.

Comment: I do not recommend deletion of this question necessarily, the keywords in the title can be used as a guide to the canonical question and answer.

Comment: Use `and` not `or`; not error or not 1 will always be true (for 1 and for error).